# Google Analytics in a web extension makes MS Edge unresponsive

Tags: google-analytics-4, web-extension

I'm working on a web extension and trying to implement Google Anaytics 4 into the extension (not GTM).

I was able to successfully implement this functionality and tested it in Firefox successfully. But when I load the plugin in MS Edge after this, the browser becomes unresponsive and I have to end the process forcefully using task manager.

Is this a known issue?
If Google Analytics is not recommended then what is a good alternative for tracking?

---

I have tried [mixpanel](https://docs.mixpanel.com/docs/tracking/javascript-quickstart) to track events too, but custom events are not being sent. Only `pageView` and `onInstalled` events are working right now.